# Format section titles as white text on black background

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I would like to redefine the `\section` and `\section*` to produce section titles that look roughly like this:
[image: illustration of desired section title formatting]
that is, text in white over a black bar that extends from left to right margin. I don't anticipate any section titles being longer than one line.

Comment: Related Q&A's: [Shaded box around multiline section heading?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56999/8272), [How to place a shaded box around a section label and name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34288/8272).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the `explicit` option for the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{white}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Another Test Section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Another Test Section with a long title spanning more than one line}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{An Unnumbered Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to use a `\parbox` of width equal to `\textwidth` (`-2\fboxsep`) inside a black `\colorbox`; inside this `\colorbox` the text is set to white using `\textcolor`.

[image]

Comment: This solution does not exhibit the expected behavior with `\section*` (it correctly does not _increment_ `thesection`, but it still _displays_ it). It also adds a lot of undesirable extra vertical space above and below the section title.

Comment: Hadn't seen your edit yet. First objection retracted. Second still stands.

Comment: @thecommexokid see my updated answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Is very nice now, yes. Could you explain what all the parts are doing?

Comment: @thecommexokid I've added a brief explanation; `\titleformat` is explained in the documentation of `titlesec`.