# How do I automate the width of \rule in section titles in \twocolumn for multiline title names?

Tags: titlesec, section-titles

I currently have problems making the \rule operation be automated to be the same width as the title when the document is in \twocolumns. Is there a way for the grey box to follow the next line of the section title at all for multiline names? I would like to still use the package titlesec if possible. Thankyou!

This is the current code that I am using right now.[image: The look of the subsection I currently have]

`\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{\rlap{\color{black!10}\rule[-0.255cm]{8.225cm}{0.9cm}} \thesubsection}{0.8em}{}`

I have referred to this article which is the closest I can find to a solution but the title names do not align as I want it to.

[Format section titles as white text on black background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58855/format-section-titles-as-white-text-on-black-background)

Please help!

Comment: That's not what "rules" are for. It looks to me that you want to have background color for the section headings? Since you are running into issues with line breaking, you probably want to use `tcolorbox` to do the background color or use `soul` to do is as highlighting. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312574/colorbox-does-not-linebreak for some ideas.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: @WillieWong I've been trying to incorporate the options into the section titles but it is not working. I have tried using \parbox but the parameter do not work within the \twocolumn layout. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I have replaced the code with a slighly simpler version. The old version is in comments.

Here is something that works. It is a bit tricky to calculate the proper widths, but this does it. The trick is you have to pick up `\linewidth` (or `\columnwidth`) while in the `twocolumn` mode, to get the proper width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength\myboxwidth

% This is my original version
% 
% \newcommand\mylabel{}
% \newcommand\myformat{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}

% \newcommand\formatmytitle[1]{%
%   \renewcommand\mylabel{\thesubsection\hspace{10pt}}
%   \setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}%
%   \settowidth{\myboxwidth}{\myformat\mylabel}%
%   \setlength{\myboxwidth}{\dimexpr \linewidth -2\fboxsep-\myboxwidth}
%   \colorbox{black!10}{\mylabel{\parbox[t]{\myboxwidth}{\raggedright #1}}}}

% \titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\myformat}{}{0pt}{\formatmytitle}

% This is the new version, which is a bit simpler.

\newcommand\formatmytitle[1]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}%
  \setlength{\myboxwidth}{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxsep}
  \colorbox{black!10}{{\parbox[t]{\myboxwidth}{%
       \setbox0\hbox{\thesubsection\hspace{0.5em}}\hangindent\wd0\hangafter1
       \raggedright\leavevmode\box0 #1}}}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\formatmytitle}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\sloppy

\section{Whatever}

\subsection{Subtracting Fractions}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! I tried using tikz as well but i think this is a simpler solution to my problem! @pietvo

Comment: but I realised it affected my Table of Contents when I switched over to your solution.

Comment: What is the problem with the table of contents? For me it looks normal.

Comment: The section number disappears for some reason but subsection and subsubsection is fine.

Comment: So I suppose you use the same solution for `\section`. When I do that, the section numbers are in the table of contents, so it must be some other code. I do have to add a `\titleformat` for unnumbered sections, however. If you still have problems with the section numbers in the table of contents, you may look into the `titletoc` package.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. Thank you so much for your help! You have been my saviour.