# Create a banner for section style

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I am wondering if there is any way to change the default style for sections. I would like to create a banner (across the page) with a dark-gray background and the section title in white. It would be great if I can also put two black bold lines on the top and bottom edge of the banner. I saw someone use TikZ to style the section but I am not familiar with that; is there any other package that can do that for me?

Comment: Are you referring to sections, as in `\section`  (in an article) or did you mean chapters, as in `\chapter` (for a book).

Comment: [How to place a shaded box around a section label and name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34288)

Comment: Hi cmhughes, thanks for the link. I follow that code, it works. But if the title of the section is too long, the shaded box won't adjust automatically to fit the new height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this could be done using `TikZ`, but there's not really need to use it here. Here's one possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\sffamily\color{white}}%
  {}{0em}%
  {{\color{black}\titlerule[3pt]}\vskip-.38\baselineskip\colorbox{gray!80}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\raggedright\strut\thesection~#1\strut}}}[\vskip-.2\baselineskip{\color{black}\titlerule[3pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\large\sffamily\color{white}}%
  {}{0em}%
  {{\color{black}\titlerule[3pt]}\vskip-.38\baselineskip\colorbox{gray!80}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\raggedright\strut#1\strut}}}[\vskip-.2\baselineskip{\color{black}\titlerule[3pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{Test Numbered Section}
\lipsum[4]
\section*{Test Unnumbered Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, it looks good. But how can I make the lines a bit thicker and remove the gaps between the lines and the box? Thanks again

Comment: @user1285419 please see my updated answer (the rule thickness can be controlled using the optional argument for `\titlerule` (I chose `3pt`); the separation between the rules and the colored box depends on the length used in the `\vskip`s).

Comment: This is a great solution. But if the section heading occurs right at a pagebreak it is possible for the titlerules to become separated from the rest of the heading. Perhaps this could be prevented by putting them inside the parbox?