# Boxed section heading style

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'd like the section title to look just as it does by default, except the following changes:

- No spacing (before/after)
- Text is inside black filled box
- Text color is white

I've tried to use the titlesec package as done in the firt answer to the following question:

[How to place a shaded box around a section label and name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/how-to-place-a-shaded-box-around-a-section-label-and-name)

However, I'm really having a hard time getting things to work with titlesec (it's not so intuitive in it's settings for me).

Comment: Could you show us what you tried that did not work, in a short but complete document (MWE)? That makes it easier for the community to identify problems and provide solutions for you.

Comment: A small picture would be helpful also.

Comment: My first attempt is this: `\let\mysection\section

\def\section#1{
\vskip-\bigskipamount \mysection{#1} \vskip-\bigskipamount
}` but I dont know the name of the space above.

Comment: @Marijn I couldn't do much more than what is provided in the example link i sent you. I've tried to move the spacings and put the section numbers inside - but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {0pt}%
                                   {0pt}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\mybox}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mybox}[1]{%
    \noindent\colorbox{blue!20}{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \textcolor{white}{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Foo bar baz bla bla}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Update** if we need some vertical space before and after

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3pt}%
                                   {3pt}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\mybox}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked! Do you know how to change the solution to add a bit of space? Like 3pts before and after?

Comment: @ndrizza try with `\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3pt}%
                                   {3pt}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\mybox}}` see update.